# sails-auth password validation failed

Tags: node.js, validation, authentication, express, sails.js

Whenever I `post` to `/user`:

[image: post image]

I get an error saying that it failed to validate password:

[image]

Validation rules:

```
attributes: {
email: {
    type: 'email',
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type: 'string',
    minLength: 6,
    required: true
}
}
```

It should succeed, but even the `required` fails while it's clearly there.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then what should I use?

Comment: @g3mini, check out https://github.com/sails101/basic-login

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `Password` to `password` in your form data. Parameters in JSON are case sensitive.

Comment: Strange. Does the email field give you errors as well, or only the password field?

Comment: Are you using sails-generate-auth / sails-auth (Passport.js)? The error seems to indicate so. If indeed so, could you provide us with some additional information on how you configured this authentication layer?

Comment: I was using sails-auth, I didn't configure much, just had it use local to do its work.